# how to store 6:00pm in sqlite database in android

Tags: android

can anybody help me how to store 6:00pm(time with am or pm) in sqlite database in android

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what you want to do with the time one might chose different data formats. If just for presentation use the String just as it is, in sqlite this is called TEXT. If you need to some kind of calculation, then I would go for java.util.Date and store its long value as an INTEGER.

If you don't need millisecond precision, try this

```
Date d = new Date(); 
int timestamp = (int) (d.getTime() / 1000L / 60L);
```

Anyhow will need to do some parsing and formatting. http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html explains data types for SQLite

Answer (score 0):

Save your data as a String in the sqlite database. I dont think it support time data type.
We can manipulate strings as we want..  this is as far as i know.

Comment: Save your time making it a string.. then while after retrieving make sub strings of it. then we can identify what time it is..:)

Comment: pls provide any sample coding for this its urgent

Comment: pls don't expect SO to do everything for you.

Comment: Brother there are many database use tutorial are available on the net. Just google it. you will find many. and to store strings and its retrieval i guess will be the most commonly found example you will get. Just google it

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Kennets answer, you can also just use String time =  Date d.toString();

and then when you pull it out of the database go Date d = new Date (time);

Answer (score -1):

Use DATETIME datatype for one colum dude.

Comment: hi ganapathy can u explain me in detail pls?

Comment: @Ganapaty, there is no Time datatype in sqlite3. See http://sqlite.org/datatype3.html (-1)

Comment: Sry dude.. its datetime type.