# How to store Time in Android SQLite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

From [how to store 6:00pm in sqlite database in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862127/how-to-store-600pm-in-sqlite-database-in-android), I know that for SQLite, there is no data type "TIME".
So, if I want to store time(year,month,day,hour,min,sec), how can I create that column? I should use "TEXT"??  But, how can I parse them for Android and
if I want to sort by time, how can I do it?
Thank for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define for yourself a date format ([link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)) and you can create let's say a `DateManager` class to convert a date to a string (to store it in the SQLite database) and to convert a string into a date, both based on that date format specified by you.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to store the `Date` as `miliseconds` (`long`).
You can get the miliseconds from a date using `date.getTime()` when you store them, and when you re-create your `Date` object you could use `Date d=new Date(milliseconds)`.

Comment: SQLite has the REAL data type, which will handle your long data.